# Spring: use properties read from a file

Tags: java, spring

i'm new to the spring framework and i'm having some problems trying to read and use properties from a file.

To summarize, what i want to do is to define a class which stores all the properties read, a second class that uses those properties to do something and a third class that uses the results.

The class that stores the properties is:

```
@Configuration
public class PropertyClass {
    @Value("${propertyName")
    private Integer propertyName;

    @Bean(name = "propertyName")
    public Integer getPropertyName() {
        return propertyName;
    }
}
```

The class that reads and uses those properties:

```
@Component
public class PropertyReader {
    private Integer myProperty;

    @Autowire
    @Qualifier("propertyName")
    public void setMyProperty(
        Integer myProperty) {
        this.myProperty = myProperty;
    }  

    public Integer getValue() {
        //do something with myProperty
        return result;
    }
}
```

And the class that uses PropertyReader:

```
public class Utilizer {
    private PropertyReader getPropertyReader() {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(PropertyReader.class);
        PropertyReader reader = (BakerStorageClassConfigHelper)context.getBean("PropertyReader");
        return reader;
    }
}
```

I've registered the classes as beans in the application-config.xml file:

```
<bean class="property.class.package.PropertyClass" depends-on="Environment" />
<bean class="reader.class.package.PropertyReader" />
```

And i have an environment.xml file where the "Environment" bean is defined with location rules to find the property files.

Now what happens that in the class "Utilizer" when i try to get the "ApplicationContext" object an exception is thrown:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'PropertyReader': 
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Could not autowire method: public void reader.class.package.PropertyReader.setMyProperty(java.lang.Integer); 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.Integer] 
found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

I've tried to change the annotation of PropertyReader class to @Repository or @Service and tried to add a @ComponentScan with the PropertyClass package specified but none of that worked for me..

Could someone give me some advices?
Thank you!

Comment: There's a myProperty parameter in the setMyProperty method that is supposed to be injected, but in fact it's not specified anywhere, is it? Maybe you could try to set this property value in the PropertyReader bean declaration.

Comment: Thank you for the advice Green... may i ask you how to do that?

Comment: Try to replace the PropertyReader bean declaratiion with this:
<bean class="reader.class.package.PropertyReader"><property name="propertyName" value="1"/></bean>

Comment: No luck, i have the same exception.. :(

Answer (score 1):

I do not quite get why do you need to declare `propertyName` as Integer. 
If what you need is just get the properties from file, then you can define a `PropertiesFactoryBean` and autowire it to any other beans you like.

Let's say you have a myValues.properties file containing values:

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
```

Define Bean:

```
@Bean(name = "myProperties")
public PropertiesFactoryBean detailQueriesFactoryBean()
{
    PropertiesFactoryBean pfb = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    pfb.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("com/xxx/myValues.properties"));
    return pfb;
}
```

Now wherever you need it, do:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("myProperties")
private Properties myValuesContainer;

public void myMethod(){
  //this will get you "value1"
  String value1 = myValuesContainer.getProperty("key1");
}
```

Hope this works for you.

--------------------- For your case----------------

If it is already in the application context, you can use `@Value` to inject value directly in your `PropertyReader` and add getter/setter for them. No need a `PropertyClass`, right?

Or you can add a @PostConstruct method to `PropertyReader`. Inside the method, you can retrieve the values you need from the existing context.

```
@PostContstruct
public void extractValues(){
    //retrieve value from context and assign to whichever var.
}
```

Comment: Thank you Leon, the fact is that the properties files are already used in different places of the application and they are loaded setting the locations in the environment.xml file. 
I need to read a subset of those properties so i defined the "PropertyClass" and i wanted to be consistent to how the rest of the application worked..

Comment: I updated the answer to your case. However i notice one thing in your code:        

ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(PropertyReader.class);
This does not look right. if you need a new appContext on the fly, you would typically pass a '@Configuration' class to the AnnotationConfigApplicationContext constructor.